# Plotting subset of a time series in R

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a time series in R. When I plot it as a whole I get 4 line charts as expected but the 4th line chart is the time.

```
timeseries <- ts(Tweets, start=c(2015, 1), frequency=42)
head(timeseries)
plot(timeseries, plot.type = "multiple", lty = 1:2, cex = .8, col = "red", main = "Time series plot of Apple frequencies")
```

Now I want to print only a subset of three line charts without the date as line chart. When I create a subset it plots just 1 line chart with three strange lines

```
timeseries.sub <- timeseries[1:nrow(timeseries) - 1, c(1, 2, 3)]
plot(timeseries.sub, lty = 1:2, col = "red", xlab = "Time", type="l", main = "Time series plot of Apple frequencies")
```

How can I plot this time series with the date on the x-axis and not as 4th line chart? I found many examples here but none really work.
Thank you Peter

Comment: Can you provide an example of the dataframe you are using?

Comment: Here is the relevant code: 
 
`Tweets<-read.csv("C:/Users/A596741/Dropbox/edu/DBA/workspace/SMAnalysis/data/Tweets/time series/Apple tot unclassified.csv")
attach(Tweets)
head(Tweets)

timeseries <- ts(Tweets, start=c(2015, 1), frequency=42)
head(timeseries)
timeseries.sub <- timeseries[1:nrow(timeseries) - 1, c(1, 2, 3)]
plot(timeseries.sub, lty = 1:2, col = "red", xlab = "Time", type="l", main = "Time series plot of Apple frequencies")` 
 
Note that it is stock data, so only weekdays are used, no weekends. Thank you. Peter

Comment: The data looks like:

 > head(Tweets)
        date Apple   open  close
1 02.11.2015  1352 119.87 121.18
2 03.11.2015  1501 120.79 122.57
....
 
 > head(timeseries)
     date Apple   open  close
[1,]    2  1352 119.87 121.18
[2,]    4  1501 120.79 122.57

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, everything is plotting fine now. Cheers